# How to get more content from database when button is clicked

Tags: php, ajax

Hello Fellow Stack Users, I have an issue. I am running a booking system and I'm in the process on changing some of the code to ajax so that the user does not have to be redirected. My database has colums. one date and the other one time. the code querys the database and gets one result for each date. december 1, december 2 etc and doesn't show the times. The issue i am having is that i can not run code which i can click the date and it will query the database to find all the time slots associated with that date.

some code below 
index.php

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT day, hour FROM availability WHERE booked='' and day >= CURDATE()";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 $next = date("M jS ", strtotime("".$row["day"] .""));
        echo "<a class='button' style='margin:10px;' href=fetch.php?pageid=" . $row["day"] . "> <p style='font-size:20px; margin:0px;'>$next</p>  ". $row["hour"]. "</a>";
    }
} else {
    echo "You are booked up for the week";
}
$conn->close();
```

fetch.php

```
   $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT day FROM availability WHERE booked='' and day >= CURDATE()";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "<a class='button' style='margin:10px;' href=book_process.php?pageid=" . $row["id"] . "> <p style='font-size:20px; margin:0px;'>$next</p>  ". $row["hour"]. "</a>";
    }
} else {
    echo "You are booked up for the week";
}
$conn->close();
```

in fetch you should click a time and then it should update the row in the process page i have not included. I am not very fluent coding ajax but i thought that now is the time to learn.

Comment: Instead of echo , store the html in a variable and echo that variable, then die; please update the question with js code @Jackbeeby

Comment: StackOverflow isn't the place for this kind of question. The short answer is that you need to learn JavaScript (the J in AJAX). A good starting point would be to learn about jQuery, which has really simple methods for handling AJAX calls.